How to row sum 'New Visual Calculation' columns in powerbi
I have a table in Power BI that shows the number of households visited per person, broken down by month. Some months may have missing data. To address this, I used 'New Visual Calculation' in Power BI to create a new constant column called "Target" using following codes.
Target = 240

The total for the "Target" column isn't summing across all months (240+240=480); instead, it just shows the constant value of 240. How can I get it to sum across all months?


Try to use a measure with the CC you created :
Target calculated = SUM(Households[Target])


